# Convert deprecated sbt build file

Tags: scala, sbt

I have this build.sbt file and the syntax used( <<= ) is now deprecated. How do I change the file so that it works again? I know there's a page documenting the changes but I'm not able to understand it properly.

```
libraryDependencies <<= scalaVersion {
    scala_version => Seq(
          ("org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.2.0").
          exclude("org.eclipse.jetty.orbit", "javax.mail.glassfish").
          exclude("org.eclipse.jetty.orbit", "javax.activation").
          exclude("com.esotericsoftware.kryo", "minlog").
          exclude("com.esotericsoftware.minlog", "minlog").
         exclude("commons-beanutils", "commons-beanutils").
          exclude("commons-beanutils", "commons-beanutils-core").
          exclude("commons-logging", "commons-logging").
          exclude("org.slf4j", "jcl-over-slf4j").
          exclude("org.apache.hadoop", "hadoop-yarn-common").
          exclude("org.apache.hadoop", "hadoop-yarn-api").
          exclude("org.eclipse.jetty.orbit", "javax.transaction").
          exclude("org.eclipse.jetty.orbit", "javax.servlet"),
          ("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-graphx" % "1.2.0").
          exclude("org.eclipse.jetty.orbit", "javax.mail.glassfish").
          exclude("org.eclipse.jetty.orbit", "javax.activation").
          exclude("com.esotericsoftware.kryo", "minlog").
          exclude("com.esotericsoftware.minlog", "minlog").
         exclude("commons-beanutils", "commons-beanutils").
          exclude("commons-beanutils", "commons-beanutils-core").
          exclude("commons-logging", "commons-logging").
          exclude("org.slf4j", "jcl-over-slf4j").
          exclude("org.apache.hadoop", "hadoop-yarn-common").
          exclude("org.apache.hadoop", "hadoop-yarn-api").
          exclude("org.eclipse.jetty.orbit", "javax.transaction").
          exclude("org.eclipse.jetty.orbit", "javax.servlet")
        )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [migration guide](https://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Migrating-from-sbt-012x.html) linked to by the warnings from sbt:

```
[info] Loading global plugins from /.sbt/0.13/plugins
//tmp/build.sbt:3: warning: `<<=` operator is deprecated. Use `key := { x.value }` or `key ~= (old => { newValue })`.
See http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Migrating-from-sbt-012x.html
libraryDependencies <<= scalaVersion {
```

You can see that you fall into the top case here:

> With simple expressions such as:

```
a <<= aTaskDef
b <+= bTaskDef
c <++= cTaskDefs
```

> it is sufficient to replace them with the equivalent:

```
a := aTaskDef.value
b += bTaskDef.value
c ++= cTaskDefs.value
```

So your `aTaskDef` is the part in between the `{}`

And as such you can fix your problem like:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies := scalaVersion {
    scala_version => Seq(
          ("org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.2.0").
          exclude("org.eclipse.jetty.orbit", "javax.mail.glassfish").
          exclude("org.eclipse.jetty.orbit", "javax.activation").
          exclude("com.esotericsoftware.kryo", "minlog").
          exclude("com.esotericsoftware.minlog", "minlog").
         exclude("commons-beanutils", "commons-beanutils").
          exclude("commons-beanutils", "commons-beanutils-core").
          exclude("commons-logging", "commons-logging").
          exclude("org.slf4j", "jcl-over-slf4j").
          exclude("org.apache.hadoop", "hadoop-yarn-common").
          exclude("org.apache.hadoop", "hadoop-yarn-api").
          exclude("org.eclipse.jetty.orbit", "javax.transaction").
          exclude("org.eclipse.jetty.orbit", "javax.servlet"),
          ("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-graphx" % "1.2.0").
          exclude("org.eclipse.jetty.orbit", "javax.mail.glassfish").
          exclude("org.eclipse.jetty.orbit", "javax.activation").
          exclude("com.esotericsoftware.kryo", "minlog").
          exclude("com.esotericsoftware.minlog", "minlog").
         exclude("commons-beanutils", "commons-beanutils").
          exclude("commons-beanutils", "commons-beanutils-core").
          exclude("commons-logging", "commons-logging").
          exclude("org.slf4j", "jcl-over-slf4j").
          exclude("org.apache.hadoop", "hadoop-yarn-common").
          exclude("org.apache.hadoop", "hadoop-yarn-api").
          exclude("org.eclipse.jetty.orbit", "javax.transaction").
          exclude("org.eclipse.jetty.orbit", "javax.servlet")
        )
}.value
```

You stated in your question:

> but I'm not able to understand it properly.

What exactly didn't you understand? If you can elaborate it might help anyone facing similar issues if it's something that I might be able to tell you more about.

Comment: I have just started learning scala and the build system/configuration along with the syntax is very alien to me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Ah, yeah sbt is a lot of black magic and trying things out with repeated `reload` commands. You can drop into a scala console with all the sbt stuff loaded to try things out by running sbt then the command `consoleProject` which lets you try things out a little bit if you want to try out examples or use the auto-complete to explore. Best place to learn things is with examples from the docs or reading sbt questions here on S.O. if you're trying to get more familiar.